# Digital or LCD-like display class?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graphics

I remember seeing a tutorial on Sun's site that had a class for a digital-like display, but I can no longer find it.

How would you make numbers appear like a digital clock, using Swing?

Comment: Where do you want to display those numbers ? console/swing app/web app/sth else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such class in Java.

That being said, if you're in Swing, you can adjust the Font settings for the text to a more digital look. On a website, you'd do it with CSS, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something [like this](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2011/11/steelseries-399.html)?

[image: lcd Component]

Or possibly more [old school](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2011/08/friday-fun-component-x.html)?

[image: Flip Chart]

Have a look at the [Harmonic Code Blog](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/), the guy writes has provides a library called the [Steel Series](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/84552/SteelSeries3/SteelSeries-3.9.24.jar) which does these components and many more.

[This entry](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2011/06/steelseries-393.html) shows of some of his clock / round gauges components.
However its best to see his components in action - he provides 2 webstart demos of his components

- [Standard Steel Series](http://idisk.mac.com/han.solo-Public/SteelSeries/test.jnlp) (direct link to webstart app)
- [Extra Steel Series](http://idisk.mac.com/han.solo-Public/SteelSeries/testextras.jnlp) (direct link to webstart app)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this tutorial](http://www.addison-wesley.de/Service/Krueger/kap23002.htm) for constructing a 7 segment display component in Java. Unfortunately it's in German. Here's [Google's translation](http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.addison-wesley.de/Service/Krueger/kap23002.htm&ei=A_MOS7KuIpLesgah8qCnAw&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CDUQ7gEwCA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Djava%2B%25227%2Bsegment%2522%2Bdisplay%2Bcomponent%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26sa%3DG).

Bah, that link doesn't show up. Here it is again: http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.addison-wesley.de/Service/Krueger/kap23002.htm&ei=A_MOS7KuIpLesgah8qCnAw&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CDUQ7gEwCA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Djava%2B%25227%2Bsegment%2522%2Bdisplay%2Bcomponent%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26sa%3DG

Again? [translation](http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.addison-wesley.de/Service/Krueger/kap23002.htm&ei=A_MOS7KuIpLesgah8qCnAw&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CDUQ7gEwCA&prev=/search%3Fq%3Djava%2B%25227%2Bsegment%2522%2Bdisplay%2Bcomponent%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Doff%26sa%3DG) .

('m gonna bug this in meta)